# How to use jdt.ast to resolve polymorphism

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm working to get the override method binding through eclipse-jdt-ast.
Just like when we using eclipse, press Ctrl and click the method ,we can jump to the method implenmentation.

Although it's dynamic binging in java, but the following works well:

```
public class Father{
public void test(){}
}
```

And Son:

```
public class Son extends Father{
@Override
public void test(){}

   public static void  main (String[] arg){
    Father f=new Son();
    f.test();
   }
}
```

When we click the test in main, we can correctly jump to the Son.java 
And I'm wondering how to do it. I tried to see the sources but didn't find the location because the code is too many.

And my code now is :

```
public class Main {
static  String filep="example/Son.java";
static String[] src={"example/"};
static String[] classfile={"example/"};

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,Exception{

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(Files.toString(new File(filep), Charsets.UTF_8).toCharArray());
    // only setEnvironment can we get bindings from char[]
    parser.setEnvironment(classfile, src, null, true);
    parser.setUnitName(filep);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    if (compilationUnit.getAST().hasResolvedBindings()) {
        System.out.println("Binding activated.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Binding is not activated.");
    }
    ASTNode node=compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode("f");
    compilationUnit.accept(new Myvisitor(compilationUnit));
}
}
```

And my visitor is:

```
public class Myvisitor extends ASTVisitor {
int i=0;
CompilationUnit compilationUnit;
Myvisitor(CompilationUnit compilationUnit){
    this.compilationUnit=compilationUnit;
}


@Override
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    IMethodBinding binding=node.resolveMethodBinding();

    ASTNode astNode=compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode(binding);
    System.out.println(astNode);
    return true;
}

}
```

It's a little long but simple, hope u can read here. Personally I guess the
findDeclaringNode method may do it. However, it returns null when I pass the binding. So do u have any ideas?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for all implementations of a given super method, the AST is of little help, as even with its bindings it only has references from sub to super but not the opposite direction.

Searching in the opposite direction uses the `SearchEngine`. If you look at `JavaElementImplementationHyperlink` the relevant code section can be found around [line 218](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/JavaElementImplementationHyperlink.java?id=ae1a3b48c9d6ee9c7c4c4e4e3a3e5682e1869f26#n218) (as of current HEAD)

You will have to first find the `IMethod` representing the super method. Then you prepare a `SearchRequestor`, an `IJavaSearchScope`, and a `SearchPattern` before finally calling `engine.search(..)`. Search results are collected in `ArrayList<IJavaElement> links`.

A good tradition of Eclipse plug-in development is "monkey see, monkey do", so I hope looking at this code will get you started on your pursuit :)

Comment: Oh, one more question, how did u find it? I tried to search but there are too many codes

Comment: To be honest, I already had a feeling you'd need the search engine, not just AST :). To get that kind of general intuition, it may help to go through one of the tutorials on JDT, like, e.g., http://www.eclipsecon.org/2012/sites/eclipsecon.org.2012/files/How%20To%20Train%20the%20JDT%20Dragon%20combined.pdf  The other option is to use the debugger to watch the tool in action.